# Why doesn't powershell regex work with \n?

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with thousands of lines, which looks something like this:

```
# RandomLocation.xaml:1234
msgid "RandomString"
msgstr ""

# AnotherLocation.cs:123
msgstr ""
```

I need to find and remove every block which doesn't have `msgid` in it, and I'm trying to accomplish that by using regex.

```
$temp | ForEach-Object{
    Select-String -Path $($DestinationPath + $culturename + ".po") -Pattern '#[: ](.)\w+.[cx][sa][m]{0,1}[l]{0,1}:\d+\nmsgstr ".*"' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {
            $_.Matches | ForEach-Object{
                $temp2 = $_.Value
                $delete.Add($_.Value)
}
}
}
```

If I remove  `\nmsgstr ".*"'` from pattern, it works correctly and detects every `# RandomLocation:1234`, however it doesn't work when I'm trying to find two lines. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

@edit: It works, however I can't remove these lines from file. It's an arraylist, and while removing single line with `$file.Remove($_.Value)` works, it doesn't when `$_.Value` has two lines.

Answer (score 1):

`Select-String` will break up the file into lines. There is no `\n` anymore when it applies the regex.

If you need `\n` to be present, read the file into one large string using `Get-Content -Raw` (without `-Raw`, `Get-Content` will *also* break the file into lines), and then pass that string to `Select-String`.

```
Get-Content -Path "..." -Raw | Select-String -Pattern "...\n"
```

That being said, your regex looks a bit suspect

```
#[: ](.)\w+.[cx][sa][m]{0,1}[l]{0,1}:\d+\nmsgstr ".*"
```

- `[m]` is the same as `m`, the character class `[]` has no effect on a single letter
- `{0,1}` is the same as `?`
- `[cx]` is *"`c` OR `x`"*, not sure if you had that in mind
- `.` means "any character", not "dot" - a dot would be `\.`

If you meant something like *"`.cs` or `.xml` or `.xaml` or `.saml`"*, it's *much* better to just write that instead of making it complicated.

```
#[: ](.)\w+\.(cs|xml|xaml|saml):\d+\nmsgstr ".*"
```

Comment: I tried your approach, however it just skips the loop and $delete stays empty, just as before. When I hover over $temp2, it shows only first line without msgstr. Also yeah, meant exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @Patryk I don't have your files and I've not debugged your regex, I only told you the reason why regexes with newlines don't match in `Select-String` by default. Look at your files closely. It's likely that you have `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Adding \r actually made that thing work. Thank you very much!